# SED command not functioning correctly

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a file test.file which has following lines.

```
abc01.hostname.com
xyzabc01.hostname.com
xyzabc02.hostname.com
```

I have script - for sed which should print output as below

```
[abc]
abc01.hostname.com
[xyzabc]
xyzabc01.hostname.com
xyzabc02.hostname.com
```

But I'm getting below output.

```
[abc]
abc01.hostname.com
[abc]
[xyzabc]
xyzabc01.hostname.com
xyzabc02.hostname.com
```

Don't know why [abc] is getting duplicated. Any suggestions?
below is the script which I am using.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `test.file | cut -d. -f1 | sed 's/[0-9]//g' | uniq`
do
    {
        name=$(cat test.file | grep ^$i[0-9] | head -1)
        sed -i "/$name/i \[$i\]" test.file
    }
done
```

Comment: Note that you currently execute `test.file` — did you mean to write `cat test.file` in the `for` loop control?  Mind you, you should be able to avoid `cat` and `cut` and just use `sed` in the control loop (you need a command to ensure uniqueness; but should probably use `sort -u`), which gives you: `for i in $(sed -e 's/\..*//' -e 's/[0-9]//g' test.file | sort -u)`

Comment: Shellcheck produces [5 findings for your code](https://pastebin.com/tg4rtZB2). You should clear them first before continuing.

Comment: You invoke `sed -i` to modify the file, and then in the next iteration of the loop you look at the modified file.  That seems like a disaster waiting to happen.  Don't use `-i`.  `sed` is designed as a streaming editor.  Use it that way.

Comment: Any time you find yourself piping grep to cut to head (or similar), think "awk is probably a better way to do this".  And consider that you almost certainly don't need a cat.

Answer (score 2):

Let's clean this up a bit.

```
for i in `cat test.file | cut -d. -f1 | sed 's/[0-9]//g' | uniq`
```

Don't do this. Don't use a subshell to supply a list to `for`, don't use `cat` to feed programs that could read the file directly, don't use a long pipeline when the subprocesses aren't needed...

```
name=$(cat test.file | grep ^$i[0-9] | head -1)
```

If you are using `bash`, there's no nead to run three (technically four?) subprocesses on every iteration to get this edited string. c.f. [this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

```
#!/bin/bash
last=''
while read name
do label="${name%%[.0-9]*}"
   if [[ "$label" != "$last" ]]
   then echo "[$label]" # or printf "\n$label\n" for a separator line
        last="$label"
   fi
   echo "$name"
done < test.file > file.redux
```

Output:

```
[abc]
abc01.hostname.com
[xyzabc]
xyzabc01.hostname.com
xyzabc02.hostname.com
```

Then if you are satisfied with the results,

```
mv file.redux test.file
```

All handled in bash quickly and efficiently with no spawning until and unless the result is good.

If you think it will be a LOT of data, try `awk` with the same logic. :)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use `sed` for this.  Just do:

```
awk '$1 != last_prefix {print "[" $1 "]"} 1; {last_prefix=$1}' FS=[0-9] test.file
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to indicate the start of line also in the `sed` command:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat test.file | cut -d. -f1 | sed 's/[0-9]//g' | uniq`
do
    {
        name=$(cat test.file | grep ^$i[0-9] | head -1)
        sed -i "/^$name/i \[$i\]" test.file
    }
done
```

Comment: Shellcheck produces [5 findings for your proposed solution](https://pastebin.com/9Ptz6bQJ).

Comment: it's the same OP script, just fixed the start of line on the sed command as commented.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'G;/^([[:alpha:]]+).*\n\1/{P;d};s/\n.*//;h;s/^([[:alpha:]]+).*/[\1]\n&/' file
```

This solution works by comparing the current key with the previous. The previous key is stored in the hold space and replaced when the key changes. On a change of key the leading alpha characters are converted into an extra record surrounded by `[` and `]`. If the key is unchanged, the current record is printed as normal.